# Write text to file literally, including special characters

Tags: bash

I want to write text to file in a bash script, literally and without modifying special characters. I search a function or command similarly to:

```
echo'line1
line2' > destination/file
```

but including all special characters inside text $ ' " (etc) and without modifying these characters.

Answer (score 13):

Easiest way is with a quoted heredoc:

```
cat << 'EOT' > /path/to/file
Thi$ is text with ' " special chars
that [ spans ] {} multiple lines
EOT
```

Note that the string "EOT" is completely arbitrary, and if you want a line in the output that consists only of the string EOT, you can choose a different delimiter.  You can also stack the here docs, so if you want some variables to be interpolated you can do something like:

```
{ cat << 'EOT'; cat << EOF; } > /path/to/file
This $var will not be interpolated in the output
EOT
But this $var will!
EOF
```

Comment: Hard to understand why there isn't a simpler way of writing heredoc that doesn't interpret special characters

Comment: How could it be simpler that adding quotes? The example I give here is perhaps overly complex in that I use two quotes instead of a simpler escaping mecahinism.  You can also do: `cmd << \EOF` instead of `cmd << 'EOF'`, but I prefer the latter for stylistic reasons.

Comment: Your answer is great. Don't get me wrong. It's just a matter of reminding one self that you can't escape having to escape your input. This solution is neat. Urrhg.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tee` command to do the same. Syntax:

```
tee filename
```

Then write the contents of the file. When you want to save, press Ctrl+Z. If you want to append to a file, then use `tee -a filename`

You can also use other commands output and pipe them to a file using tee.